# How can I read and use vb.net cookies in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I am creating asp.vb cookies...

```
Response.Cookies("theatres")("thearches") = "'253 Argyle St, Glasgow G2 8DL', 'The Arches'"
Response.Cookies("theatres")("thecitz") = "'119 Gorbals St, Glasgow G5 9DS', 'The Citizens'"
```

[alternatively have tried

```
Dim myCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("UserSettings")
myCookie("Font") = "Arial"
myCookie("Color") = "Blue"
myCookie.Expires = Now.AddDays(1)
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)
```

]

and i want to use them in a javascript function. So i know i can read them in javascript with...

```
var cookieArray = document.cookie
document.write(cookieArray)
```

However when i try and separate out the different cookies with document.cookie.split(';') nothing happens. I want to know how to access each cookie separately. Do I do this with an array? I've looked at load of examples using...

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}
```

but still don't know how exactly to apply this to what i'm doing.

Comment: vbscript is NOT vb.net - changed your tag

Comment: What does `document.write(cookieArray)` print out?

Comment: theatres=thearches='253 Argyle St, Glasgow G2 8DL', 'The Arches'&thecitz='119 Gorbals St, Glasgow G5 9DS', 'The Citizens'